# Dismissing Child View in SwiftUI TabView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI TabView with two tabs, and one of the tabs presents a child view using NavigationLink. What I want to achieve is that when I tap on the tab item of the parent view (the one that presented the child view), it should dismiss the child view and return to the parent view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("View1")
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Child View")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Go to child view")
                    }
                }
            }
            // when child view is presented, I want when I tap on the tab item view the child view to dismiss. How can I achieve this?
            .tabItem {
                Label("view1", systemImage: "1.circle")
            }
            
            Text("View2")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("view2", systemImage: "2.circle")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried various approaches, including using .onChange and @Environment(.presentationMode), but I haven't been able to make it work as expected.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior in SwiftUI when using a TabView and presenting a child view? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using NavigationStack + NavigationPath you can clear the path onChange of the TabView selection

Comment: i don't want path to be cleared only in change of TabView selection even if it is the same tab when tabItem pressed i want child view to dismiss

Comment: There is no way to know when the user clicks on an already selected tab with the built in tab view, you have to create your own so you can have a Button that checks your logic and acts appropriately. You still need a NavigationStack though so you can clear the path.

Comment: I have noticed that these features are present in most popular apps, such as WhatsApp. Does this mean that apps like these use a custom tab bar?

Comment: I don’t know what they use but I am pretty sure they don’t use SwiftUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two ways to achieve what you want:

1. Using the `.id()` API to reset the `NavigationLink`.

```
enum TabSelection {
    case first
    case second
}

private final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabSelection = TabSelection.first
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    @State private var tab0Id = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $viewModel.tabSelection) {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("View1")
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Child View")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Go to child view")
                    }
                    .id(tab0Id)
                }
            }
            .tag(TabSelection.first)
            .tabItem {
                Label("view1", systemImage: "1.circle")
            }

            Text("View2")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("view2", systemImage: "2.circle")
                }
                .tag(TabSelection.second)
        }
        .onReceive(viewModel.$tabSelection) { newValue in
            if newValue == .first {
                tab0Id = UUID()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

2. Injecting the view model as an `EnvironmentObject` into the child view:

```
enum TabSelection {
    case first
    case second
}

private final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabSelection = TabSelection.first
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $viewModel.tabSelection) {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("View1")
                    NavigationLink {
                        ChildView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Go to child view")
                    }
                }
            }
            .tag(TabSelection.first)
            .tabItem {
                Label("view1", systemImage: "1.circle")
            }

            Text("View2")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("view2", systemImage: "2.circle")
                }
                .tag(TabSelection.second)
        }
        .environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss: DismissAction
    @EnvironmentObject private var rootViewModel: ContentViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Child View")
            .onReceive(rootViewModel.$tabSelection) { newValue in
                if newValue == .first {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

**EDIT:** Just a Side note: if you need to reset the navigation ONLY when you are on the first tab and you tap on the first tab item, you can just change the logic in the `onReceive` like this:

```
.onReceive(viewModel.$tabSelection) { [oldValue = viewModel.tabSelection] newValue in
    if oldValue == .first && newValue == .first {
        tab0Id = UUID() // or `dismiss()` if you prefer the second way I described here above
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]